# Error: Type "DetailViewController" does not to protocol VKSdkDelegate

Tags: swift, delegates

I have simple code:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, FBLoginViewDelegate, VKSdkDelegate {
```

Xcode an error: Type "DetailViewController" does not to protocol VKSdkDelegate

What advise do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IN VKSDKDelegate there are some required methods. You can see them here http://vkcom.github.io/vk-ios-sdk/Protocols/VKSdkDelegate.html So, if your class use VKSdkDelegate protocol, just realize this required methods